# How can I get the RSA fingerprint dialog back?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, samsung-galaxy

I need to be able to resume debugging a webpage I wrote which is misbehaving in some of the browsers on my phone.

I have a Samsung A5 (2017) and Samsung phones apparently have some special challenges in getting connected to laptops for debugging, as discussed in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions...evices-does-not-detect-device-when-plugged-in

Fortunately, I was using the technique in the second suggested technique (by studocwho) and it was working well until I did a slight variation on his technique: when I changed the USB Connection from MTP (Media Transport Protocol) to Audio Source and the dialog about the RSA key appeared, I checked the checkbox thinking that this would cause the RSA fingerprint to be sent from my phone to my laptop automatically each time so that I wouldn't get the RSA fingerprint dialog any more, save a couple of seconds, and still connect to the laptop.

As it turns out, that is NOT what happened at all. For whatever reason, it stopped giving me the dialog and also failed to send the RSA fingerprint to the laptop AT ALL. The laptop just waits patiently for me to accept the debugging session on the phone (see screen shot) but the phone does absolutely nothing at all. Apparently, checking that checkbox prevents the RSA fingerprint from being sent so no debugging session can start at all.

[image]

How do I get that RSA dialog to appear again so that I can start my debug session? I have to believe there is SOME way to reverse the effect of checking that checkbox but I'm darned if I know what it is. I've tried rebooting the phone but that didn't do it.

Comment: @halfer - Why did you edit my question? You didn't change the meaning one iota. It seems as if it wasn't even a suggestion, you just changed it as if you knew better what I wanted to say than I did. Was I violating some kind of rule with the original wording?

Comment: Morning Henry. It's not a violation exactly, more of a guideline. We prefer technical writing here, as we find the succinctness and neutral form to be easier to read, especially for people who have English as a second language. There's several resources in the Help Centre and in Meta that indicate mutual editing is completely normal here: [such as here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) and [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

Comment: A "guideline" implies something where I have the option of not following it but I had no option here: you didn't ask if you could make this change, you simply did it and now appear to be rationalizing it by pointing to other instances where other people did the same thing. That sounds more like a rule to me! And worse, I still have no idea what the nature of the rule is. What exactly was wrong with the original wording?

Comment: Yes, editors do not ask for permission before editing (with the caveat that editors under 3K rep have to have their proposed edits reviewed by the community). I advise you to read the links I have supplied. If you are still dissatisfied, use the flag feature on the question and raise a custom mod flag, or post a public message on Meta, linking to this question.